# How to hide the original confirm in JavaScript onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, onbeforeunload, confirm

I'm creating a game in a web page and I think it will be better, if when the user accidentally click back (in tablet or phone) then will appear a confirm box to stay.

I would like to use an own style confirm box (with more options) instead of the original. Well, now I use `onbeforeunload` JavaScript Event. Although I can't change the style, I can add more things to do when it happens. So I think if it can be hidden, then it's enough for me :D

Comment: It is not possible (apply styles or create a custom modal for confirmation in `onbeforeunload`).

Comment: This has been asked before.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/276739/2337565

Comment: Ok, I can't change that, but is it possible to rewrite this event to don't show any confirm box and don't go back? Just stay here and call my function?